What’s the difference between these three phrases: “On the basis of”, “On a basis of”, “On a + adj/N + basis”?

We developed our society _______.

Which option out of the three should I use to fill in the blank:

on the basis of equality
on a basis of equality
on an equality basis

And what’s the difference between these 3?

A bit more smooth than all these would be "We based our society on equality."

On the basis of is an idiom meaning

according to : based on
Students were chosen/selected on the basis of their grades and test scores.

We could use it with equality.  Answer (1) is valid.
On a basis of is not valid.  Try keying that into Google, and you get the results for the the version.
On an equality basis
has lots of hits too but is much less common
than the idiom.  Answer (3) is valid too and means the same as answer (1).

My perception, as I just start to think about it, is that "on a ___ basis" is often used in specialized fields like finance. But I guess also things like "I schedule my appointments on a day-to-day basis." Hm. There are definitely some uses in which it fits and some in which it doesn't, but I haven't put my finger on why.
